# Debbuging MS Graph API Errors when using Powershell

Tags: powershell, debugging, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently trying to setup a powershell-script which does the basic configuration for new tenants our company sets up.

Since I've had to start using the MS Graph API I've hit a wall. For many Settings all across the Azure Cloud, MS provides some cmdlets to call the Graph-API for configuration. Example:

```
Get-MgDeviceManagementDeviceConfiguration
```

This gets currently configured Windows 10+ Update Rings. This works fine, I get an appropriate answer from the Graph API and see all the options configured. So now that I want to make my own configuration using the following cmdlet:

```
New-MgDeviceManagementDeviceConfiguration
```

I provide the BodyParameters which seem appropriate (and I've got it working for AuthenticationMethods configuration using Update-MgPolicyAuthenticationMethodPolicyAuthenticationMethodConfiguration) but all I'm getting back is just "One or more errors occured.":

```
New-MgDeviceManagementDeviceCompliancePolicy : One or more errors occurred.
At line:9 char:5
+     New-MgDeviceManagementDeviceCompliancePolicy -BodyParameter $para ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-MgDeviceMan...cePolicy_Create], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.NewMgDeviceManagementDeviceCompliancePolicy_Create
```

Is there a way to actually debug something like this? Using the -Debug parameter does not show the HTTP call but a StackTrace that does not help:

```
DEBUG: [CmdletException]: Received exception with message 'AggregateException - One or more errors occurred. :    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.EventFactory.CreateLogEvent(Task`1 message)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.NewMgDeviceManagementDeviceConfiguration_Create.<>c__DisplayClass47_0.<Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Runtime.IEventListener.Signal>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.NewMgDeviceManagementDeviceConfiguration_Create.<Microsoft-Graph-PowerShell-Runtime-IEventListener-Signal>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---...
```

Any idea how to debug those "not-so-well-documented" cmdlets?

Thanks.

Comment: The error says it failing when doing a CREATE.  Start troubleshooting using following : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/troubleshooting-assistance-with-microsoft-graph-api-development/ba-p/510062